# Save IEnumerable into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have model:   Its data from some site, where I parse it.

```
public class Race
{
   [Key]
   public int Id;
    public string Cars;
    public string Place;
    public string Pilot;
}

var compare = Doc.DocumentNode
                 .SelectNodes(path)
                 .Select(s => new Race()
                            {
                                Cars =s.SelectNodes("./div[1]//text()").Single().InnerText,
                            }
                        );
using (_context) //  how can I do this?
{
    _context.Race.Add(compare);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

> Argument 1: cannot convert from '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Race>`' to 'Race'

Comment: LINQ usually returns IEnumerables, even if there is only one item in the list. Do a LastOrDefault() on the IEnumerable to get only the last or default one. (remember to check if the LINQ returned something first maybe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `AddRange` instead of `Add`

```
using (_context)     //  how can I do this?
{
    _context.Race.AddRange(compare);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```